# Using Storyboards and trying to call a view controller from another view controller

Tags: storyboard, viewcontroller

I apologize in advance for a likely simple question.  I am using XCode 4.4 and am trying to simply call a 2nd view controller when a button is pressed to show info about my app.  I have created a 2nd view controller (SecondViewController) and seem to have the appropriate .h and m files.  I added a view controller to the storyboard and changed the view controller's class to SecondViewController.

On the fist view controller, i simply have a button that calls the showSecond Method i created.

When I execute the app via the simulator and press the button on the first view controller, the screen flips as expected but it goes to a black screen and not the screen I customized in the storyboard scene.

Here is the code snippet from the initial view controller.m file:

```
-(IBAction)showSecond
{
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Following a tutorial, I was able to get this to work without the storyboard method, but it required a slightly different init function as it references a xib file.  I am trying to use storyboards as much as possible and am new to xcode programming.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Comment: what language is this exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a really easy way to show another view with a button. Add another UIView Controller to your storyboard.  Then right click on the button from the first view and drag the connection to the second view.

Comment: Thanks.  This was helpful.  I also figured out that if you add a new File of Objective-C class and make a subclass of the UIViewController, a .h and .m file are created.  You can then change the UIViewcontroller class within the Storyboard to match the filenames and there put code to execute when the view loads within the new ViewContollers .m file.